# Cannot mount AWS S3 bucket/path using s3fs on CentOS 7

Tags: s3fs

From a CentOS 7 virtual machine running on Azure, I am unable to mount an AWS S3 bucket using s3fs. The path part of the bucket location is removed before s3fs checks for bucket's existence:

```
s3fs version 1.90(unknown) : s3fs -f -o dbglevel=debug,endpoint=eu-west-1,profile=customer,bucket=company-sftp:/Customer/dev /srv/test_s3/
s3fs_logger.cpp:LowSetLogLevel(240): change debug level from [CRT] to [DBG]
    s3fs.cpp:set_mountpoint_attribute(4094): PROC(uid=1000, gid=1000) - MountPoint(uid=1000, gid=0, mode=40755)
s3fs.cpp:s3fs_init(3382): init v1.90(commit:unknown) with OpenSSL
s3fs.cpp:s3fs_check_service(3516): check services.
      curl.cpp:CheckBucket(3388): check a bucket.
curl_handlerpool.cpp:GetHandler(81): Get handler from pool: rest = 31
curl.cpp:ResetHandle(1945): The CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_ALPN option could not be unset. S3 server does not support ALPN, then this option should be disabled to maximize performance. you need to use libcurl 7.36.0 or later.
curl.cpp:ResetHandle(1948): The S3FS_CURLOPT_KEEP_SENDING_ON_ERROR option could not be set. For maximize performance you need to enable this option and you should use libcurl 7.51.0 or later.
      curl_util.cpp:prepare_url(254): URL is https://s3.amazonaws.com/company-sftp/
      curl_util.cpp:prepare_url(287): URL changed is https://company-sftp.s3.amazonaws.com/
curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2283): connecting to URL https://company-sftp.s3.amazonaws.com/
      curl.cpp:insertV4Headers(2680): computing signature [GET] [/] [] []
      curl_util.cpp:url_to_host(331): url is https://s3.amazonaws.com
curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2363): HTTP response code 403, returning EPERM. Body Text: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>[...]</RequestId><HostId>[...]</HostId></Error>
```

The "customer" profile contains credentials for an IAM user that can access only the /Customer/dev part of the bucket.

Using the same S3 bucket and credentials, I don't get the same behavior using sshfs 1.86-1 (and libcurl 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7) on Ubuntu 20.04.3 :

```
s3fs -f /home/dleborgne/s3 -o dbglevel=debug,endpoint=eu-west-1,profile=customer,bucket=company-sftp:/Customer/dev
[CRT] s3fs.cpp:set_s3fs_log_level(297): change debug level from [CRT] to [DBG]
[INF]     s3fs.cpp:set_mountpoint_attribute(4400): PROC(uid=1000, gid=1000) - MountPoint(uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=40755)
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_init(3493): init v1.86(commit:unknown) with GnuTLS(gcrypt)
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_check_service(3828): check services.
[INF]       curl.cpp:CheckBucket(3413): check a bucket.
[DBG] curl.cpp:GetHandler(289): Get handler from pool: rest = 31
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4703): URL is https://s3.amazonaws.com/company-sftp/Customer/dev/
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4736): URL changed is https://company-sftp.s3.amazonaws.com/Customer/dev/
[DBG] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2384): connecting to URL https://company-sftp.s3.amazonaws.com/Customer/dev/
[INF]       curl.cpp:insertV4Headers(2753): computing signature [GET] [/Customer/dev/] [] []
[INF]       curl.cpp:url_to_host(99): url is https://s3.amazonaws.com
[INF]       curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2416): HTTP response code 200
```

In one case (s3fs 1.86 on Ubuntu), s3fs checks for credentials using `https://company-sftp.s3.amazonaws.com/Customer/dev/` while on the other (s3fs 1.90 on CentOS), it uses a trimmed url `https://company-sftp.s3.amazonaws.com/` and fails.

I'm puzzled about this difference and welcome any idea.

Comment: Finally ended up using [Goofys](https://github.com/kahing/goofys)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on my side.

I guess, there is a problem with URL handling, you can look at the logging lines:

RHEL / CentOS not working

```
URL is https://s3.amazonaws.com/company-sftp/
URL changed is https://company-sftp.s3.amazonaws.com/
computing signature [GET] [/] [] []
```

Ubuntu, working

```
URL is https://s3.amazonaws.com/company-sftp/Customer/dev/
URL changed is https://company-sftp.s3.amazonaws.com/Customer/dev/
computing signature [GET] [/Customer/dev/] [] []
```